# How to parse json with retrofit on Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I try to write app which parse decoding of abbreviations and frequency of their use. User input abbreviation, for example "kg". So, app should connect to "http://nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf=kg" and parse it.

What should model classes look like? Did I describe @Geth correctly in the interface? How can I get the list, I made an adapter, bind it to the list, but I'm not sure about getResponse ().

Interface:

```
public interface SService {

@GET("dictionary.py?")
Call<Example> getResponse(@Query("sf=") String searchString);
}
```

Retrofit client:

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

And addition class ApiUtils

```
public class ApiUtils {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/";

public static SService getSOService() {
    return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(SService.class);
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<Lf> elements = new ArrayList();
EditText editText1;
ElementAdapter stateAdapter;
ListView list;
private SService mService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    mService = ApiUtils.getSOService();

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_list);
    
    stateAdapter = new ElementAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, elements);
    
    list.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
}




public void loadAnswers() {
    mService.getResponse(editText1.getText().toString()).enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                stateAdapter.updateAnswers(response.body().getLfs());
            } else {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                // handle request errors depending on status code
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}


public void activity_button(View view) {
    //stateAdapter.clear();
    loadAnswers();
}
}
```

UPD!!
All input data is an array: Array[Object{...}]. Right interface for parsing it:
public interface SService {

```
@GET("dictionary.py")
Call<List<Example>> getResponse(@Query("sf") String searchString);
}
```

So, we get with Call List with Example object (Only one object in this case).

Comment: @GET("dictionary.py?") remove the "?" in your GET. Retrofit will automatically add the "?" and "&" when you have @Query in your arguments.

Comment: Also return type must be array and enable clear traffic in manifest because you make request over `http`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `SService` interface to the following,

```
public interface SService {

@GET("dictionary.py")
Call<Example> getResponse(@Query("sf") String searchString);
}
```